# regex to match all tabs whose url ending with an image.extention(png,jpg,...) including local files url(file:///)

Tags: javascript, css, regex, styles

**Regex to match all** tabs whose **url ending with an image.extension**(png,jpg,...) including local files url(file:///)

↑ For Applying Custom Styling through An Extension Like Stylus

Example:

```css
body {
    background: repeating-conic-gradient(from 0deg, #ccc 0% 25%, #fff 0% 50%) 0px 0px/5vh 5vh fixed !important;
    /* ↑ via https://css-tricks.com/background-patterns-simplified-by-conic-gradients/#cp_embed_GRprppy */
}

svg {
    background: repeating-conic-gradient(from 0deg, #ccc 0% 25%, #fff 0% 50%) 0px 0px/5vh 5vh fixed !important;
}

/* MacOS Style Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: solid #fafafa;
    min-height: 15px;
    min-width: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #a8a8a8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** I found correct regex(accidentally) ↓

```
(.*)(\.png|.jpg|.jpeg|.avif|.gif|.svg|.mp3|.mp4)
```